# Error with findByUserIsCurrentUser generated by entity subgenerator SpelEvaluationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

2022-09-01 16:52:18.073 ERROR 79129 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:53) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:300) ~[spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$ExpressionBasedQueryParameterSetterFactory.evaluateExpression(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$ExpressionBasedQueryParameterSetterFactory.lambda$create$0(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1080) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162.findDealersBySalesPersonIsCurrentUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.nexcar.prv.service.OrganizationService.findDealersBySalesPerson(OrganizationService.java:342) ~[classes/:na]
at com.nexcar.prv.service.OrganizationService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e431aa1.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at com.nexcar.prv.service.OrganizationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a35bb710.findDealersBySalesPerson() ~[classes/:na]
at com.nexcar.prv.rest.OrganizationResource.getSalesPersonDealers(OrganizationResource.java:338) ~[classes/:na]
at com.nexcar.prv.rest.OrganizationResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3a3143d3.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at com.nexcar.prv.rest.OrganizationResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b89a38fa.getSalesPersonDealers() ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at com.nexcar.prv.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:84) [classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.nexcar.prv.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:84) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.nexcar.prv.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:84) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]

2022-09-01 16:52:18.077  WARN 79129 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'principal' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?]

i have a query in repository like this

@Query("select organization from Organization organization where organization.salesPerson.login = ?#{principal?.username}")
List findBySalesPersonIsCurrentUser();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Spring Data & Spring Security integration you must add the `org.springframework.security:spring-security-data` dependency and expose a `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` bean, like so:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/data.html